# Nginx doesn't honor connection: close

Tags: php, nginx

I have the following php code, that works fine when running under Apache, but I was not able to make it work under Nginx:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-length: 0');
session_write_close();
flush();
// continue on background
```

Under Nginx, in my experience, the browser keeps connection alive until time-out which produces '504 Gateway Time-out'.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't test this atm, but try `fastcgi_finish_request()`

Comment: How simple... This does exactly what I need! Thanks!!